# view pdf page in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

am doing paging to read pdf file page by page  and open the page in browser 
I tried to use itextsharp and itext  but it return the page as text 
is there any way to read the pdf file page and view it in broser exactly as in pdf with formating

Comment: Have you tried open parameters? http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You could you use the [Embeddable Google Document Viewer](http://googlesystem.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html)

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: thx for your answers but i need to read it page by page cuz am using ajax to read page by page and i need to select text inside the pdf page if its possible

Comment: what i mean how can i send page paramameter
i tried this but doesn't work 
       #:3.page.5

Comment: Could you add some code to your question so we can see where you are up to

Comment: Dim PdfFileName As String = "c:\data\1.pdf"   

        Dim oReader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(PdfFileName)  

dim strpagepdf as string  

        For pageid = 1 To oReader.NumberOfPages  

            Dim its As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy  

            strpagepdf = iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(oReader, pageid, its)  

        Next

Comment: now i get the result as text only how can i get it as formatted pdfpage so i can put it inside div in html
thx for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use an iframe and point its src to the PDF.  It will still invoke the client's PDF reader, but will be embedded in your page.

Comment: ok i just only need to read specific page not to load all  pages
because some file size is very big